# Random walker algorithm how a gray-level image can be 3D?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image, random-walk

- I was reading the source of the [random walker algorithm](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/segmentation/random_walker_segmentation.py) in **scikit-image** library, and it's written there that:

> Parameters
>
> ---
>
> ```
> data : array_like
>     Image to be segmented in phases. Gray-level `data` can be two- or
>     three-dimensional
> ```

**My question is:** what do they mean by 3D gray-level image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2D image is an image that is indexed by (x,y). A 3D image is an image that is indexed by (x,y,z).

A digital image samples the real world in some way. Photography produces a 2D projection of the 3D world, the digital photograph is a sampling of that projection. But other imaging modalities do not project, and can sample all three dimensions of the 3D world. For example:

- [Confocal microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confocal_microscopy)
- [Computed tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CT_scan)
- [Magnetic resonance imaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging)

Besides these, a 2D time-series (a movie) is sometimes also treated as a 3D image, applying algorithms that work on 3D images.